# What does the Jacobi identity *mean* statistically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, error-analysis

Given that the commutator of a pair of operators shows up explicitly in the lower bound of the Robertson-Schrodinger inequality, I am wondering what, if any, statistical meaning/significance one can attach to the Jacobi identity of three operators containing all their pairwise commutators. Is there any?